Proof of convergence of a modified alternating harmonic series with a trigonometric term.
I'm having trouble understand the validity of the answer given by MSE user Jack D'Aurizio on https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3059137/810055. My understanding of his proof is as follows:
We take $f(z) = \sum\limits_{n \geq 1} \frac{|\sin(n)|z^n}{n}$ which we know converges absolutely for $|z| < 1$, and try to study its convergence on the border specifically at $z = -1$, that is $\sum\limits_{n \geq 1} \frac{|\sin(n)|(-1)^n}{n}$.
We notice that by $\pi$-periodicity we have the following fourier decomposition for some coefficients $a_m$, $|\sin(x)| = \sum\limits_{m \geq 0} a_m \cos(mx)$ and in particular $|\sin(n)| = \sum\limits_{m \geq 0} a_m \cos(mn)$. The Fourier series converges uniformly, due $a_m \sim \frac{1}{4m^2}$, so there isn't any problem here.
This gives us the following expression for $f$:
$$f(z) = \sum_{n \geq 1} \sum_{m \geq 0} a_m\frac{z^n}{n}\cos(mn)$$
Assuming we can interchange the order of summation (Fubini does not apply here as the series does not converge absolutely) we would have:
$$f(z) = \sum_{m \geq 0}a_m \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{\cos(mn)z^n}{n}$$
Through the complex form of $\cos(x)$ we can arrive at the following form for the right summation.
$$f(z) = \sum_{m \geq 0} a_m \Re\big(\log(1-ze^{im})\big)$$
Which comes from the Taylor Series expansion of $\log(1-z)$ which converges absolutely for $|z| < 1$ however we are interested in taking $z = -1$ which is not in the interior of the disk. It is well known that the real part of a logarithm, regardless of branch cut is just the logarithm of the absolute part, hence we obtain:
\begin{align*}
f(z) &= \sum_{m \geq 0} a_m \log|1-ze^{im}|\\
&= \tfrac{1}{2} \sum_{m \geq 0} a_m \log|1-ze^{im}|^2\\
&=\tfrac{1}{2} \sum_{m \geq 0} a_m \log((1-z\cos(m))^2 + (z\sin(m))^2)\\
&= \tfrac{1}{2} \sum_{m \geq 0} a_m \log(2-2z\cos(m))
\end{align*}
And so for $z = -1$ we obtain
\begin{align*}
f(-1) &= \tfrac{1}{2}\sum_{m \geq 0} a_m \log(4 \cos^2(m/2))\\
&= \log(2)\sum_{m \geq 0} a_m + \sum_{m \geq 0} a_m \log|\cos(m/2)|
\end{align*}
And from approximations valid for all except a finite number of $m$, given through the irrationality measure of $\pi$ as well as noticing $a_m \sim \tfrac{1}{4m^2}$ we conclude convergence.
My question is, how would we go about proving that the change of variable was valid? And that the Taylor series expansion of the logarithm that was used is valid for all $m$, at $z = -1$?

In my experience with infinite series being manipulated in this way evaluating on the boundary of an open set can often times work out but sometimes doesn't and the best way to see if it works out is if the final awnser agrees with numerical results. You could just leave it open for any z and then take a limit to see if the limit exists.

Sure, but the thing that I'm actually interested is in the proof of those exchanges of limits being valid cause we know the end result works out
